# Can you convert a html project into reactjs?

Tags: html, reactjs, type-conversion

I wonder if is an easier way to convert an HTML project into a react.js project.

I mean, I can integrate all the CSS, HTML, and JS but is not regular HTML, which is generated by a framework named Nicepage, dunno if you guys know it.

Comment: Easy way, no...

Comment: Ok i guess I have to hard code it